# Force Diagram for K&K 2.13

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

I have been (independently) working on Problem 2.13 in Kleppner and Kolenkow's *An Introduction to Mechanics* and come to an answer which conflicts with the hint the authors provided in the book. The problem is this:

> A "pedagogical machine" is illustrated in the sketch.  All surfaces are frictionless. What force $F$ must be applied to $M_1$ to keep $M_3$ from rising or falling?

[image: MS Paint approximation of original picture]

(Note that $M_1$ is sitting on a level plane which is not drawn in my reproduction of the original sketch.)$\\$

I have three or four pages of matrix manipulations and derivations which led me to my answer, but since I think my error is in my force equations and not in my manipulations I won't post everything I've done unless someone requests that I do so. Let $\vec{F}_{M_3}$ be the force on $M_{1}$ from $M_{3}$, let $\vec{F}_{M_{1}}$ be the force on $M_3$ from $M_1$, and let $\vec{a}_n$ be the acceleration vector for $M_n$. For each vector $\vec{u}$, let $\vec{u}=\left<u_{x},u_{y}\right>$ and $\vert\vec{u}\vert=u$.  The vectors $\vec{T}_1$ and $\vec{T}_2$ are tension forces.

$$\vec{F}_{M_3}+\vec{F}=m_{1}\vec{a}_1\\
\vec{T}_{2}=m_{2}\vec{a}_{2}\\
\vec{T}_{3}+\vec{F}_{G_3}+\vec{F}_{M_1}=m_{3}\vec{a}_{3}$$

Since $a_{1x}=a_{1}=a_{3x}$, $F_{M_3}=F_{M_1}$, and $T_{2}=T_{3}$, I find (letting $a_{3y}=0$),

$$
F-F_{M_3}-m_{1}a_{3x}=0\\
T_{3}-m_{2}a_{3x}=0\\
F_{M_3}-m_{3}a_{3x}=0\\
T_{3}=m_{3}g
$$

Putting the corresponding matrix into row reduced echelon form gives

$$F=\frac{m_{3}g\left(m_{3}+m_{1}\right)}{m_{2}}.$$

The hint provided in the book says:

> For equal masses, $F=3Mg$.

My answer gives $F=\frac{Mg(M+M)}{M}=2Mg$. Have I properly accounted for all forces which do not cancel in my force equations?

Comment: I have edited the original question. If my force equations are incorrect then there is a misunderstanding on my part of the concepts involved in the problem. I put a fair amount of effort into clearly presenting my problem and the work I have done to solve it myself, in part to show that my problem *is* conceptual as opposed to computational (if my math is easy to verify, then it is clear that my error is in identifying the forces involved, not in my manipulations of the equations I have written). Also, it may be that there is a typo in the book (I made it easy to verify). Please reopen this.

Answer (score 3):

You are introducing some irrelevant variables, as $F_{M_3}$, $T_1$, $T_2$. Let us make the assumption that $T_1=T_2=T$ (the pulley doesn't rotate and the string is massless). *The whole* has mass $M=m_1+m_2+m_3$, accelerates with $a$   and the force on $M$ is 
$$F=Ma.$$ 
The tension $T$ equals $m_2 a$ and also $m_3g$, so$$a=\frac{m_3}{m_2}g.$$Hence $$F=\frac{m_3}{m_2}Mg.$$

The error in your analysis is that there's another force applied to $M_1$, namely the force exerted by the wire on the pulley. This has a horizontal component equal to $-T=-m_2 a$, as a bit of thought shows. Adding the $m_2a$ term to your first equation, everything works out.

Comment: And here's your mistake: the force on $m_1$ is not only $F+F_{M_3}$... there's also the force exerted by $m_2$!

Comment: As above: I saw the force exerted by $M_2$, but wouldn't the sum of the that force and the force of gravity on $M_1$ be met with a normal force of equal magnitude from the plane $M_1$ slides over? If that were not the case, then wouldn't $M_1$ be accelerating in the direction of $-\hat{\mathbf{j}}$?

Comment: @flakmonkey I've added some explanation

Answer (score 1):

Hint.
I think the error is in your first equation, adding the forces for mass M1:
$\vec{F}_{M_3}+\vec{F}=m_{1}\vec{a}_1\\$.
There is an additional force on M1 that you have omitted.

Edit: The pulley exerts a force on M1.

Comment: For brevity I wrote the equation that way, but when I worked on the problem I wrote: $\vec{F}_{M_2}+\vec{F}_{M_3}+\vec{F}_{G1}+\vec{F}_{N}+\vec{F}=m_{1}\vec{a}_1$. But wouldn't $\vec{F}_{M_2}+\vec{F}_{G1}+\vec{F}_{N}=\mathbf{0}$?